# Please clear my query about this python code using the requests module returning response code 503

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
html_text = requests.get('http://www.amazon.in/s?k=iphone&ref=nb_sb_noss_2')
print(html_text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get Response `200`, use `User-Agent` HTTP Header:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:89.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/89.0"
}

html_text = requests.get(
    "http://www.amazon.in/s?k=iphone&ref=nb_sb_noss_2", headers=headers
)
print(html_text)
```

Prints:

```
<Response [200]>
```

Comment: Thanks!, could you please explain what changed in this code, I am a beginner to web scraping?

Comment: @YashTripathi Some websites block content from bots/scrapers such as `requests` by checking the `User-Agent` HTTP header the client sends. With `headers=` parameter, we are changing this header to mimick a standard browser.